# VirtualHost DocumentRoot cgi goes to `/var/www`

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, httpd, cgi

I have an apache based web server I am called to do some maintenance on a few times a year.  For this purpose I keep a local mirror so I can do what's required then upload the changes.

I haven't used apache for anything else in a long time, and since I've upgraded my workstation since the last time, I had to install it. I have a `.conf` file I drop into `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and this has never been a problem in the past.

That last version of apache I used was probably 2.2, so this time with 2.4.18 I got a warning about the depreciation of `NameVirtualHost`, but the actual `<VirtualHost>` section *seemed* to be fine.

Until I got to the part I have to work on, a set of `.cgi` scripts.  Inside the VirtualHost .conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /mnt/lan/foo/bar
        ServerName hullabaloo.mirror
        <Directory /mnt/lan/foo/bar/cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        </Directory>
        [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

There's an `.htaccess` in that directory to the same effect too (`Options +ExecCGI`), which is there because the actual production server is configured to require it (not my department).

Anyway, as mentioned most links are fine.  However, a form which uses a `.cgi` script returns 404, and in the logs I find:

```
AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/search.cgi, referer: http://hullabaloo.mirror/search/index.html
```

Of course there is no `/var/www/cgi-bin` anything.  It's in `/mnt/lan/foo/bar/cgi-bin`, which is readable by the process and the `search.cgi` file is world executable. That's also the same tree it has also been pulling local links from which is how I got to `http://hullabaloo.mirror/search/index.html`.

The link in the html page is:

```
<form method="post" id="searchform" action="/cgi-bin/search.cgi">
```

As far as I can remember all this worked fine the last time I had to do anything (about 6 months ago); I am very meticulous and would have made changes (that `.conf` file is only part of my mirror) and/or left notes.

What is the problem here?  **There is a symlink in the `/mnt/lan/foo/bar` path**, if that matters as of 2.4.  I have not started throwing darts at random possibilities yet.

I have had a look at the request going from the browser to the server and it is definitely using `http://hullabaloo.mirror/cgi-bin/search.cgi` as the URL.

Comment: is `/mnt/lan/foo/bar` a symlink or `/mnt/lan/foo/bar/cgi-bin`?

Comment: It's the `lan` part -- the mirror is on another drive who's mount point varies, but `lan` links to whatever it currently is.

Comment: Are you following symlinks globally in your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: If you mean `FollowSymLinks`, the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) say this can only be applied in a `<Directory>` section, so I've added `Options +FollowSymlinks` to every `<Directory>` to which tha path could possibly include, restarted, no change.   Also *non cgi* pages are fine.  Notice the error log isn't even giving the right path -- it refers to `/var/www/cgi-bin`.

Comment: Oh I just found a `ScriptAlias` in the main .conf...

Comment: ...low and behold that seems to have solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if previous versions of apache had this by default in the main `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file or not -- this is actually from a Fedora package.

```
<IfModule alias_module>

    [...]

    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
```

I can see how this could be a security thing in cases where people are free to add their own `.htaccess` or `.conf` files but can't alter this one, and those people aren't supposed to be running subprocesses.

Anyway, commenting out the `ScriptAlias` line solved the problem.